# Drag and Dropping an Object Reference VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, reference, drag-and-drop, object

I am trying to 'swap' two cells' contents, and their mappings. To do this, I need to drag and drop a reference to the cell as opposed to the string value itself. I can then use this reference to update a Dictionary as well as get the value. It allows allows me to do the swap as I will have a reference to the old cell to add the value needed in there.

The problem I am having is I am not sure how to pass the cell reference:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseDown
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        DataGridView1.DoDragDrop(DataGridView1.CurrentCell, DragDropEffects.Copy)
    End If

End Sub
```

and in the drop event:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DragDrop

   'Problem is here -->'Dim copyedFromCell As DataGridViewCell = DirectCast(e.Data(), DataGridViewCell)** 
    Dim copyedFromKey As String = GetMappingForCell(copyedFromCell) 
    Dim thisKey As String = GetMappingForCell(DataGridView1.CurrentCell)
    Dim copyedFromValue As String = copyedFromCell.Value
    Dim thisValue As String = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value

    mappings(copyedFromKey) = DataGridView1.CurrentCell
    mappings(thisKey) = copyedFromCell

    DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = copyedFromValue
    copyedFromCell.Value = thisValue

End Sub
```

Is what I am trying to do possible? Have I completely broken it? Thanks :)

Comment: When I drag from the current cell it gets selected upon the mouse click, however when I want to drop somewhere else in another row, the target cell doesn't get selected and hence the current cell doesn't hold its reference while I want to update it.
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`e.Data`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drageventargs.data.aspx) is a [`IDataObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.idataobject.aspx), **not** the value you sent with `DoDragDrop`.

To get the value you sent, you must call [`e.Data.GetData(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94ckfkxz.aspx).

To fix your code, replace the problem line with:

```
Dim copiedFromCell As DataGridViewCell = _
   e.Data.GetData(GetType(DataGridViewTextBoxCell))
```

(or whatever the type of `DataGridView1.CurrentCell` is.)

You can get a list of types available to be dropped by calling [`e.Data.GetFormats()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1745023c.aspx).