# Enabling dropping of custom object into a usercontrol

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2017, oledragdrop

I've created a usercontrol with VS2017 in VB.NET.

Dropping a file from the desktop works fine, but I want to drop a custom object (a cell from a 3rd party grid control) onto it, which doesn't work.

How can I implement such a drop in my usercontrol?
Do I need to make an invisible label and move this with the 3rd party grid cell so that the usercontrol recognizes that some "native" control should be dropped, or what would be the way to make something draggable (like the file from the desktop) at all?

Comment: `ucBoardGrid.AllowDrop = True` Putting this in your form load work/help?

Comment: @Cal-cium Unfortunately not.

Comment: you can set the form to allow drag and drop, and then use your drag and drop events to make it work maybe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drag and Dropping an Object Reference VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321471/drag-and-dropping-an-object-reference-vb-net)

Comment: @Cal-cium I don't know why but now it works with your suggestion. Can you make your comment the answer, please?

Comment: @tmighty done :) glad its working

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34190140/3110834) are steps of drag and drop with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the usercontrol to allow drag and drop in the Form_Load

```
ucBoardGrid.AllowDrop = True
```